# In Android Maps V2, is there a way to control the positioning of the map when a marker is tapped on?

Tags: google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

Currently, by default, when tapping a marker, the map centers on the marker. Is there a way to control that, introduce some offset values. I have a popup info window that is a little taller at times and I would like to position the map so it does not get cut off at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could likely override the GoogleMap marker click event and adjust the camera there.

For example

```
Maker lastOpened = null;

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) { 
        // Check if there is an open info window
        if (lastOpened != null) {
            // Close the info window
            lastOpened.hideInfoWindow();

            // Is the marker the same marker that was already open
            if (lastOpened.equals(marker)) {
                // Nullify the lastOpened object
                lastOpened = null;
                // Return so that the info window isn't opened again
                return true;
            } 
        }

        // Open the info window for the marker
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        // Re-assign the last opened such that we can close it later
        lastOpened = marker;

        // Get the markers current position
        LatLng curMarkerPos = marker.getPosition();

        // Use the markers position to get a new latlng to move the camera to such that it adjusts appropriately to your infowindows height (might be more or less then 0.3 and might need to subtract vs add this is just an example)
        LatLng camMove = new LatLng(curMarkerPos.latitude + 0.3, curMarkerPos.longitude);

        // Create a camera update with the new latlng to move to            
        CameraUpdate camUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(camMove);
        // Move the map to this position
        mMap.moveCamera(camUpdate);

        // Event was handled by our code do not launch default behaviour.
        return true;
    }
});

mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        if (lastOpened != null) {
            // Hide the last opened
            lastOpened.hideInfoWindow();

            // Nullify lastOpened
            lastOpened == null;
        }

        // Move the camera to the new position
        final CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(point).zoom(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom).build();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    });
```

This code hasnt been tested but should at least give you a great start at it. The default behavior of onMarkerClick is to move the camera and open the info window. So overriding this and implementing your own should allow you to move the camera where u please.

Thanks, DMan

Comment: There is a small omission in the logic DMan. lastOpened needs to be reset when the user taps outside the marker, and the info window disappears. Otherwise a good solution.

Comment: @oviroa Good catch, I couldn't recall if the marker closed onMapClick or not. I've updated the answer (can you please mark as the correct answer to help others out). Thanks, DMan

Comment: Actually, one more thing. The lastOpened field is not needed. You can just check for marker.isInfoWindowShown(). Also lastOpened.hideInfoWindow() is not necessary, it is taken care of by default.

Comment: @oviroa Even in the instance that you click a marker that is not the opened marker? I figured that if you open a marker then click a different marker you'd be required to close the previously opened one as we are overriding the default behaviour of closing and navigating to the newly opened marker. Always good to know though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I modified the really nice answer above for anyone who just wants to remove the move-to-center default behavior of the marker click:

Add this to setUpMap():

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(getMarkerClickListener());
```

And then add method:

```
Marker lastOpened = null;

public OnMarkerClickListener getMarkerClickListener()  {
    return new OnMarkerClickListener()  {
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) { 
            if (lastOpened != null) {
                lastOpened.hideInfoWindow();
                if (lastOpened.equals(marker)) {
                    lastOpened = null;
                    return true;
                } 
            }

            marker.showInfoWindow();
            lastOpened = marker;
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Gets my +1.  Worked like a charm straight out of the box.  Thanks!